# PHP file size upload condition not working

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Hi i am trying to upload file and sets the limit 1 mb.
when file size is greater than 1 mb file doesn't move in folder but it updates in in mysql database.

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$fileNameTmp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
$fileExtension = explode('.',$fileName);
$fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileExtension));
$maxsize = 1000000;
$fileUniqueName = uniqid().'.'.$fileExtension;
$store = 'uploads/'.$fileUniqueName;

if($fileSize>$maxsize)
{
echo 'size exceed';
}
else
{

    move_uploaded_file($fileNameTmp,$store);
    $query = mysql_query("update users set image = '$fileUniqueName' where id = '$_SESSION[id]'");
}
?>
```

Expected result: file name should not update in database if size exceeds 1 mb.

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Your code is likely vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: `var_dump($maxsize, $fileSize);` and check if the values are what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the file didn't upload and you're getting `$fileSize` equal to 0, bypassing your if condition.
Change it to `if($fileSize > $maxsize || $fileSize == 0)` to capture the error.

Comment: That's why your if condition is getting bypassed. Change it to 
`if($fileSize > $maxsize || $fileSize == 0)`

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the correction. Please mark it as correct :)